# unity project error during export to html5

Tags: python, html, unity-game-engine

When i create a blank project on unity 5 and i try to export it to html5, the following message error appears:
Failed running "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport/BuildTools/Emscripten_Win/python/2.7.5.3_64bit/python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport/BuildTools/Emscripten/emcc" @"C:/projetos unity/new project/New Unity Project 1/Assets/../Temp/emcc_arguments.resp"

stdout:
stderr:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport/BuildTools/Emscripten_FastComp_Win\llvm-link: C:/Users/f�bioandrews/AppData/Local/Unity/Editor/EmscriptenCache/libcxx.bc: error: Could not open input file: N�o existe mapeamento para o caractere Unicode na p�gina de c�digos de m�ltiplos bytes de destino
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport/BuildTools/Emscripten_FastComp_Win\llvm-link: error loading file 'C:\Users\f�bioandrews\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\EmscriptenCache\libcxx.bc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport/BuildTools/Emscripten/emcc", line 1166, in 
    shared.Building.link(linker_inputs, in_temp(target_basename + '.bc'), force_archive_contents=len([temp for i, temp in temp_files if not temp.endswith(STATICLIB_ENDINGS)]) == 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\webglsupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 1330, in link
    assert os.path.exists(target) and (output is None or 'Could not open input file' not in output), 'Linking error: ' + output
AssertionError: Linking error:

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

What can i do to solve this error? Is there a way to change the EmscriptenCache folder location? I think the error is my user name folder that has a Unicode character: fábioandrews